# Weird behavior when startActivityForResult a singleInstance Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I created three Activities in an android app: `MainActivity`, `SecondActivity`, `ThirdActivity` and log the `onCreate@taskId` event of those Activities.

The launch mode of `SecondActivity` is set to `singleInstance`.

Then I put two buttons in `MainActivity`.

button1 `startActivity(SecondActivity)`.

button2 `startActivityForResult(SecondActivity)`.

button3 `startActivity(ThirdActivity)`.

After click button1 -> click button3 I got the following log, which is as I expected:

```
MainActivity onCreat@xxx0
SecondActivity onCreate@xxx1 // second activity is expected in a new task
ThirActivity onCreate@xxx0 // third
```

But, click button2 -> click button3:

```
MainActivity onCreat@xxx0
SecondActivity onCreate@xxx0 // it seems that startActivityForResult will make singleInstance activity not work
ThirdActivity onCreate@xxx1 // Here is the weird thing, the ThirdActivity is created on a new task!
```

Can someone explain this?

Here is the repo [singleInstanceTest](https://github.com/aztack/singleInstanceTest) for reproducing.

Comment: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` should work.

Comment: @Raghunandan I add this flag when start SecondActivity, nothing changed.

Comment: It should work with the intent flag second activity launches in a new task

Comment: It seems `singleInstance` does not work with `startActivityForResult`. I think if you want to keep current behavior, then from MainActivity, just using startActivity(secondActivity). Then using broadcast or EventBus to return result to MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

The [documents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#ManifestForTasks) said

> if an instance of the activity already exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance.

I using the definition of `singleTask` launch mode to explain that behavior because it sames

1. When you click to `Button 1` it start `SecondActivity` and when you get back (I assume you press back or call `finish`) the instance of `SecondActivity` pop out `BackStack`
2. When you click to `Button 2` instance of `SecondActivity` not exits so `System` will create a new instance for `SecondActivity`

To understand about it you should try follow `MainActivity` -> `startActivityForResult(SecondActivity)` -> Create button in `SecondActivity` start `ThirdActivity` -> in `ThirdActivity` create button and call `startActivityForResult(SecondActivity)`. Log it to understand.